# Mouse locks up when using QTimer::singleShot repeatedly

Tags: windows, qt, timer

I'm developing a Qt 4.8.4 GUI application targeting Windows 7. I'm trying to implement the ["Solving a Problem Step by Step"](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html#solvingaproblemstepbystep) approach to keep the GUI responsive during a long-running computation, which is nicely divisible into many small steps.

Here is a minimal working example of this technique:

**Computation.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "QtCore/QCoreApplication"
#include "QtCore/QDebug"
#include "QtCore/QObject"
#include "QtCore/QTimer"

class Computation : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
 public:
  Computation() : amount_(0) {}

 public Q_SLOTS:
  void start() {
    amount_ = 100000;
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(calculate()));
  }

 private Q_SLOTS:
  void calculate() {
    if (--amount_ > 0) {
      qDebug() << "Calculating..." << amount_;
      //QCoreApplication::processEvents();
      QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(calculate()));
    } else {
      qDebug() << "Finished";
    }
  }

 private:
  int amount_;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Computation.h"

#include "QtCore/QDebug"
#include "QtGui/QApplication"
#include "QtGui/QMainWindow"
#include "QtGui/QPushButton"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  Computation computation;

  QMainWindow window;
  QPushButton button(&window);
  button.setText("Test");
  QObject::connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &computation, SLOT(start()));

  window.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

There's also a [CMakeLists.txt](http://pastie.org/7437938) for this example in case anyone wants to try it out.

Now, on to the actual problem: when the computation is running, certain GUI interactions lead to a lockup of the mouse. The cursor can still be moved, but clicking on any part of the desktop has no effect at all in this state. The computation still goes on. The only way to escape this lockup is to switch to another application with the keyboard (e.g. Alt+Tab, pressing the Windows key, or Ctrl+Alt+Del) or to wait until the computation has finished.

The GUI actions which lead to this state include attempting to move or resize the application's main window. Instead of changing the window's geometry, the mouse lockup explained above happens. However, the window instantaneously jumps to the position is was to supposed to be moved to as soon as the computation finishes (and you didn't switch to another window in between).

Opening the system menu (by clicking on the application symbol in the title bar) also leads to similar behavior, but this time only the application (including the system menu) is indifferent to mouse clicks.

I tried to work around this problem by issuing [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) in my `calculate()` method (commented line in the above example). This only helped a little: instead of locking up the mouse *every* time one tries to move or resize the window, you now have to do it about 3-5 times to trigger the behavior. Different combinations of [`QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#sendPostedEvents) and [`QCoreApplication::flush()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#flush) didn't help either.

How can I solve this problem? Is this a known Qt bug and/or is there a workaround?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use Threads?

Comment: @Misch I'm already doing the bulk of the work in a separate thread and pushing results to a synchronized queue. But updating the GUI with the new results must happen in the main/GUI thread, which is why I somehow have to trigger the "calculate" method in the GUI thread from time to time to see if new results have come in.

Comment: I agree with Misch. Using a separate thread would stop the locking of the main UI thread.

Comment: If I understand you right, you mean that `calculate()` really just means "fetch results"?

Comment: @CameronTinker I've included the implementation in the header for brevity. It does nothing useful in this minimal example besides some debug output.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a problem, but if `calculate()` is really that short, then most of the CPU time is just used to add the task to the queue and then pop it again, and make the next calculation. Maybe you would get better results if you made more (100? 1000?) calculations at once and only then call QTimer again?

Comment: I know that in .NET when I make threaded applications, I offload long running processes to new threads and update controls in the UI thread using `Invoke` from within the separate threads. I'm not exactly sure how to do the same implementation in Qt, but it should be a similar concept.

Comment: Well, I just tested your code, there is absolutely no problem with this code on linux. I also tried to make 1000 calculations at once, and only then call `QTimer` again, which also doesn't make any noticeable difference.

Comment: @Misch Thanks for testing it on Linux! I already suspected it's a Windows thing. The behavior on Windows doesn't change no matter how long `calculate()` takes.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more: I'm developing some sort of 3D viewer. The worker thread loads parts of a 3D scene from disk and pushes them into a queue. The actual upload of the scene data to the GPU has to be made on the GUI thread. Emitting a signal from the worker thread every time something has been loaded and handling the upload in a slot on the GUI thread in one go is not possible, as this might block the GUI thread for too long. So I have to handle the queue of loaded data a small bit at a time, allowing the GUI to react to user input in between.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make an application multi-threaded, you can use Qt's slots and signals architecture. Just emit a signal from your thread when something changes. Then in your UI thread, connect a slot to the signal from your thread:
[Qt: Background thread refreshing UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376835/qt-background-thread-refreshing-ui-thread)

Answer (score 0):

Using QThread is definitely a better strategy than chunking the computation and trying to do everything in one thread.

Then in the calculate thread, use a timer every 1/15 sec (for example) to call a signal that has been connected to a slot in the main thread, which informs the UI to update any data you want to see from the calculations.